# vuejs - how to add vue-material theme

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

I am starting a `vuejs` project using `vue-cli`.

I want to use `vue-material` as the main look and feel but I am not sure how to change the theme color.

from `vue-material`:

> To use custom themes you'll need SCSS/SASS support in your project.
>   Read more about Pre-Processors. In the near future you'll be able to
>   use themes with Plain CSS and Stylus too.

and provide with this code:

```
@import "~vue-material/dist/theme/engine"; // Import the theme engine

@include md-register-theme("default", (
  primary: md-get-palette-color(green, A200), // The primary color of your application
  accent: md-get-palette-color(pink, 500) // The accent or secondary color
));

@import "~vue-material/dist/theme/all"; // Apply the theme
```

which I created a `style.scss` to include them.

and from `vuejs` come with this code:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted

      // this will apply to both plain `.scss` files
      // AND `<style lang="scss">` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  // plugin omitted
}
```

First of all, there isn't any `webpack.config.js`. but there is a `babel.config.js`. So i created `webpack.config.js` and include the code too.

When I run `npm run serve`, nothing seems to happen. there isn't any error or warning too.

I am new with `webpack` and I really not sure how this all work.

Answer (score 0):

`vue-cli` doesn't have a `webpack.config.js` file. You don't need to make one. Instead, you can put your options inside `build/webpack.base.conf.js`.

Comment: I can't find the `build/webpack.base.conf.js` too. do I need to create one? I want it to work with both `.vue` file and final build, how should I set them?